# Using emacsclient with custom emacs in $PATH

Tags: emacs, executable, path

I want to use `emacs` command as a substitution for `emacsclient -c -a ""`, which according to man connects to an existing emacs daemon, or creates a new daemon and connects to it otherwise. So i created a shell script `emacs`, which calls the aforementioned command in my `~/bin`, which itself is included in `$PATH`. But when i run `emacs`, it repeats the following numerously:

```
emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?
To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start".
```

and then also numerously:

```
Error: Could not start the Emacs daemon
```

The content of `~/bin/emacs` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
emacsclient -c -a ""
```

According to [Emacs devs](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=11572), `emacsclient` internally calls `emacs` from `$PATH`, so calling it enters an infinite recursion. What should i do, so i can use custom `emacs` executable with the same behavior?

Comment: The content of your wrapper is?

Answer (score 3):

Not directly an answer but how about making a shell alias instead of writing your custom script, e.g:

```
alias emacs='emacsclient -c -a ""'
```

This allows you to type emacs in your interactive shell and everything should work out of the box.

Another idea is that you either modify `PATH` in your `~/bin/emacs` script and exclude `~/bin/` or export a variable before running `emacsclient` and check in your script if the variable is set and run the original emacs command instead.